# How to use a variable to call the name of a row in a imported csv

Tags: function, powershell, csv, variables

```
function UpdateCSV
{
param(
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$path,
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$Row,
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$exportpath,
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$Delimiter
      )
try{$csv = import-csv "$path" -Delimiter $Delimiter | Select-Object *,@{ Name= 'Department' ; Expression= {'Unkown'} },
                                                                      @{ Name='Office' ; Expression= {'Unkown'} }, 
                                                                      @{ Name= 'ADStatus' ; Expression= {'Unkown'} }
    }
catch{break}


$result = foreach($user in $csv){
    $userrow = $user.$row
    write-host "$userrow"
    $Username = $userrow.trim()
    $ADUser = get-aduser -Filter {name -like $Username -or CN -like $Username -or sAMAccountType -like $Username} -Properties * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if(!$ADUser){
    $user.Department = "No ADUser"
    $user.Office = "No ADUser"
    $user.ADStatus = "No ADUser"
    }


else{
    $user.$row = $Username
        if($ADUser.department -gt $null){$user.Department = $ADUser.department}
        else{$user.Department = "Empty"}
        if($ADUser.office -gt $null){$user.office = $ADUser.office}
        else{$user.Office = "Empty"}
    $user.ADStatus = $ADUser.enabled

}
$user

}
$result | export-csv "$exportpath" -Delimiter ";" -ErrorAction Stop

}
```

What I am trying to do is let a parameter reference the name of the row where I have the users name but when i user `"$user.$row"` it doesn't work and in the `write-host` section it writes out the full column instead of only the row I specify in `$row`

But if I instead hardcode `$userrow = "$user.example"` it works directly and in the `write-host` section it only writes out the that value instead all of the column

So the question is how do I call upon a row that i have the name of in a variable.

This is the first time writing something that will be used by others than me, so please do point out if there is some glaring misstakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is $_.columnheading

When you import-csv and then pipe it, the column heading is the name of the value.
If you imagine each row as your object and each column heading as the values of the object. When you import-csv, each object is piped through individually.

$_ is the current object that has been piped through. Therefore:

```
$_.department or $_.name etc. will have the value you are looking for.
```

I hope this makes sense and is answering your question.

Thanks, Tim.

UPDATED AFTER COMMENTS

```
try{$csv = import-csv "$path" -Delimiter $Delimiter | Select-Object *,@{ Name= 'Department' ; Expression= {'Unkown'} },
                                                                  @{ Name='Office' ; Expression= {'Unkown'} }, 
                                                                  @{ Name= 'ADStatus' ; Expression= {'Unkown'} }
                                                                  @{ Name= 'User' ; Expression= {$_.columnheadingforusercolumn}
}


$result = foreach($user in $csv){
  $userrow = $user.user
  write-host "$userrow"
}
```

Comment: Not sure i follow here, code in the try block is working as excpted.

I struggle to call $user.$row in the foreach loop. This is since i can't predict the name of the $row since it will be diffrent from each system we audit

Comment: In your try block, you can use the expression you need to match up the name. If you add Name = 'User' ; Expression = { $_.columnnameforuser } to your hash table, your user title will always be the same. 

When your CSV changes, you will need to update the hash table and its expressions to collect the correct data. Everything after that should then be able to stay the same. For example $userrow = $user.user etc

Comment: The columns i add are working as excepted and i can call upon them as excepted. It's the column that i ask the user to name in the $row variable that i don't manage to call upon.

The three rows i add I don't have any issues with, the row i have an issue with is the one that is already in the CSV since I do not know the name and hence i need to user $user.$row. If I am missunderstanding you, could you show a snippet of how it would work?

Comment: Yes It's a bit clearer, fiddled around and made it work for me. Proposed an edit to your post to show how it worked for me. Thanks for the help mate

Comment: No worries Jako. Glad I could help. On mobile at the moment. Thanks for the edit. Will update the edit when I get to my PC. Cheers mate.